# ES6 Proxies for location.pathname changes

Tags: javascript, es6-proxy

Is it possible to use ES6 Proxies to track changes of `location.pathname`?

As far as I know, Proxies can be used for objects, and `location.pathname` is an object, right?

If the answer is yes, can someone help me understand how to achieve this?

The only working thing I managed to create is the following code:

```
const handler = {
  get(target, key) {
    console.log(`Reading value from ${key}`)
    return target[key];
  },
};

const p = new Proxy(location, handler);
console.log(p.pathname);
```

But the above code will only show once the current URL is in the browser's tab.

How can I make it work to keep tracking the changes?

Comment: *"will only show once the current URL is in the browser's tab"* - what does this mean?

Comment: @Spectric Will print once in the console when you run the command.

Answer (score 3):

`window.location` is a nonconfigurable getter/setter, which means that it can't be replaced:

```js
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(window, 'location'));
```

The same is true for the `.pathname` property of the object returned by the getter:

```js
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(window.location, 'pathname'));
```

And a `location` variable can't be declared on the top level:

```js
const location = { newObject: 'foo' };
```

Which means that there's no way to intercept changes to it by replacing it with a Proxy - any references or assignments in the existing code to `window.location.pathname` will necessarily invoke the browser's built-in implementation.

Comment: So there's no way we can achieve this by using Proxies? Regarding the browser, I use Chrome.

Comment: That's right, unfortunately - unless you can change the source code that references `window.location.pathname` to instead reference something like `myProxy.pathname`, you can't change and/or detect when that occurs by using a Proxy.